# Use Perl + Regex to Change #define to #undef in C++

Tags: c++, regex, bash, perl

Inside of a large configuration file I have something like:

```
#define DO_THIS_NOW // Set DO_THIS_NOW before running y
```

I would like to have a simple perl one-liner that can change this to:

```
#undef DO_THIS_NOW
```

Sometimes, however, it may actually have an extra space or two:

```
#define   DO_THIS_NOW // Set DO_THIS_NOW before running y
```

The solution I was looking at would be something along the line of:

```
perl -MPOSIX -pe's/define DO_THIS_NOW/undef DO_THIS_NOW/e' file.h > file.h.2
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax quite right.

Is this the best way to go about doing this? Or is there an obvious other way to do it? My end-game is to put the perl one-liner into a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match one or more whitespace characters using `\s+` syntax.

```
perl -pe 's/define\s+DO_THIS_NOW/undef DO_THIS_NOW/' file.h > file.h.2
```

- `\s` matches a single whitespace, like space, tab etc.
- `+` modifier matches one or more of whatever it follows

The `/e` modifier evaluates the replacement string as perl code and replaces the matched text with the result of the evaluation. It is not necessary for this replacement.

Look at `perldoc perlretut` for more information.

Comment: Awesome! The /e modifier was my main problem and causing the errors. Thanks.